# PCIe Bus Error Severity=Corrected

Tags: 15.10

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 on a HP B&O Pavilion Core i5.  Everything works fine except when I enter TTY1-TTY6 there is a continuous error message scrolling. The (I assume) address is constantly changing

```
pcie port 0000:001c.0 pcie Bus Error: Severity=Corrected, Type Physical 
Layer, id=00e0 (Receiver ID)  device [8086:a115] error 
status/mask=00000001/00002000 [0] Receiver Error
```

When I entered suspend the scrolling stops, but so does the ability to use the network.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem with my HP notebook and posted a new question for it here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/759607/pcie-bus-error-messages-on-boot-and-shutdown

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume I have not asked the question correctly, or that no one has the answer.  I have reloaded Kubuntu 14.04.3 on the HP B&O Pavilion Core i5. in hopes of correcting the problem.  It did correct the initial problem in that it will now connect to the network without scrolling continuous error messages, but the operating system will not stay connected to the internet.(that is not exactly correct, because the network symbol on the desktop says it is connected to the network) The browser will not connect to the network or internet, after a couple of minutes it says it cannot find the server.  If I restart the computer everything connects, and works.  If I let the computer set, say overnight, it somehow loses the connection.  I can only assume there is some sort of incompatibility between the network adapter and the operating system. The network adapter is; Realtek Semiconductor C., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter.  I will continue searching for an answer.  If anyone has any ideas please don't hesitate to give me a shout.  Thanks.